# How to replace a specific character string with a number?

Tags: r, gsub

I'm working with a dataframe, entitled Clutch, of information about cards in a trading card game. One of the variables, CMD+, can consist of the following values:

```
"R+1"
"L+1"
"R+2"
"L+2"
0
```

What I want to do is to create a new variable, Clutch$C+, that takes these string values for each data point and replaces them with numbers. R+1 and L+1 are replaced with 0.5, and R+2 and L+2 are replaced with 1. 0 is unchanged.

How do I do this? Sorry if this is a basic question, my R skills aren't great at the minute, working on getting better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably not the most beautiful solution but this should work.

```
C<-rep(0,length(Clutch$CMD))
Clutch<-cbind(Clutch,C)
Clutch$C+[which(Clutch$CMD+=="R+1")]<-0.5
Clutch$C+[which(Clutch$CMD+=="L+1")]<-0.5
Clutch$C+[which(Clutch$CMD+=="R+2")]<-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
paste0(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "\\1", x))/2, sub("\\D", "\\1", x))

[1] "0.5+1" "0.5+1" "1+2"   "1+2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using the fact that the result is half the digit in your string :

```
Clutch <- data.frame(`CMD+` = sample(c("R+1", "L+1", "R+2", "L+2", 0), 10, replace = TRUE))

Clutch[["C+"]] <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", Clutch$CMD))/2

Clutch

> Clutch
   CMD.  C+
1   R+1 0.5
2   R+2 1.0
3   R+1 0.5
4   L+1 0.5
5   L+1 0.5
6   R+1 0.5
7   R+1 0.5
8   L+1 0.5
9     0 0.0
10  L+1 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `gsub`

```
> as.numeric(gsub(".*[+]","",a))/2
[1] 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0
```

If it is a  `data frame`. You can use this-

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.frame(CMD = c("R+1", "L+1", "R+2", "L+2", 0))
> setDT(dt)[,CMD:=as.numeric(gsub(".*[+]","",a))/2]
> dt
   CMD
1: 0.5
2: 0.5
3: 1.0
4: 1.0
5: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use a simple `ifelse` statement that looks for `1` in the string and replaces with 0.5, and `2` to replace with 1, i.e.

```
#where x is your column,

as.numeric(ifelse(grepl('1', x), 0.5, ifelse(grepl('2', x), 1, x)))
#[1] 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0
```